# Git merge request to branch which is a source branch of another merge request

Tags: git, branch, git-merge

Let's say I have a situation like this:

```
    |
   _|
  | task2
 _|
| task1
|
|
master
```

And task1  branch is already on merge request to master. Then, I want to merge task2 as well. I select target branch `task1` cuz then on MR I can see only those commits which were created on task2 branch, not task1+task2.

So the situation looks something like this:

```
  <-|
<--_|
  | task2
 _|
| task1
|
|
master
```

Merge request from task1 to master and merge request from task2 to task1.

My question here is simple. What should be a correct way to merge those? Should I first merge `task2->task1` and then `task1->master` or should I do `task1->master` and then `task2->master`?

And by the way, whatever option is the right one, will I end with unique commits from those branches? And by unique I mean master + task1 + task2, and not like master + task1 + task1's part of task2 + task2?

Answer (score 0):

I think task2 should be asking to be merged into master, not task1... and the right order to merge would then be first task1, then task 2. If you merged task2 directly into master before task1, task1 would be merged as part of task2.

Comment: I know I am commenting a 1 yo answer here, but through this year I discovered that I pretty much like to have linear history with fast-forward merges. In that case I would merge task1 to master. Then rebase task2 to master and merge it. This way I will end up with exactly what I've needed and I don't even need (though I can have it) an additional commit specifying the merge.

By the way, if I would do this like you've suggested I would have to rebase task1 to master, which would stack my task1's commit on top of all the commits from master (co tastk1 + task2), so I would duplicate the commit